# Google Tag Manager Link Click Event Listener Triggering on Page Load

Tags: html, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am having an issue that all of my Link Click Event Listeners are being triggered every time the page is loaded rather than when a user click the links.

Here is the setup for the listener:

[image: tag-manager detail pictures]

This is the code of the link that I am trying to track.  There are a number of these generated in a Wordpress query loop:

```
<a class="bookButton" target="_blank" href="http://testlink.com"><span id="3BDCNH">Book Now</span></a>
```

I moved the ID on to a span wrapping the text rather than on the link trying to see if that would change the issue.  No difference between having it on the `<a>` tag or the `<span>` tag.  Both still fire every time the page is loaded rather than when the user clicks.

Comment: If a tag fires when the id is on the span  then it cannot be fired by the rule in your question - the linkClick event handler does not work on span tags (that would take a generic click handler). So you should look if there is another rule that auto-fires your tag.

Comment: I changed it to the span based on a different article that seemed to have a similar issue.  So the issue I am having occurs with the id on the a tag as well.

Comment: Are you sure this rule is firing? Use the GTM debug mode to find out all the tags and rules that fire on your page to be sure. Can you post the tag configuration (including all firing rules).  As Eike Pierstorff stated, this rule isn't causing a tag to fire on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The gtm.linkClick listener should be configured in a tag of its own to load on every page so that it listens to every and all clicks to any links. Your event should then be configured to fire when the event is gtm.linkCLick. This resource is helpful: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/auto-event-tracking-google-tag-manager/.